# How to access values in DF to write a text using R markdown?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a processed dataframe as follows (the list of staff differs for different weekly reports):

[image]

```
df <- structure(list(Department = c("DP1", "DP1", "DP2", "DP2", "DP2", 
"DP4"), `Staff Name` = c("Bray Laura", "Fognani Mikaela", "Despain Taylor", 
"Housum Zachary", "Herman Trenton", "Burgette Lesley"), `Non-compliance Criteria` = c("0 temperature reporting for >/= 3 days", 
"0 temperature reporting for 2 consecutive readings", "0 temperature reporting for 2 consecutive readings", 
"0 temperature reporting for 2 consecutive readings", "0 temperature reporting for 2 consecutive readings", 
"1 temperature reporting/day for >/= 5 days")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

There are 4 fixed values in `Department`:

1. `DP1`
2. `DP2`
3. `DP3`
4. `DP4`

And 3 fixed values in `Non-compliance Criteria`:

1. `0 temperature reporting for >/= 3 days`
2. `0 temperature reporting for 2 consecutive readings`
3. `1 temperature reporting/day for >/= 5 days`

The list of `Staff Name` will differ for different weekly reports.

I would like to output the texts in R markdown as follows:

[image]

I wish to access the values in the dataframe and write it out in text and bullet points. So within, a `Department`, we would show the list of staff that are non-compliant and which criteria they fulfill. If within a `Department`, >1 staff fulfill the same criteria, we would collapse them with "," and "and" as shown in "DP2" example.

I was stuck after this:

```
non_compliants <- df %>% 
  group_by(Department, `Non-compliance Criteria`) %>% 
  summarise(Text = paste(paste(`Staff Name`, collapse = " and "), "had", unique(`Non-compliance Criteria`))) %>% 
  ungroup()

lapply(c("DP1", "DP2", "DP3", "DP4"),
       function(x){
         ifelse(dim(filter(non_compliants, Department == x))[1] == 0, 
                "NA", 
                non_compliants$Text[non_compliants$Department == x])})
```

Comment: Replace the ' with backticks - this demonstrates how to execute code inline with the text, just then modify to return the desired bits of your dataframe where appropriate: `'r paste("Patient A scored", rnorm(1,0,1), "in test 6)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a character-string that simulates a markdown syntax... So, you can do like this in your Rmarkdown:

```r
persons <- sapply(c("DP1", "DP2", "DP3", "DP4"),
       function(x){
         ifelse(dim(filter(non_compliants, Department == x))[1] == 0, 
                "NA", 
                non_compliants$Text[non_compliants$Department == x])})

text <- sapply(names(persons), 
               FUN = function(person){

                 paste("###", person, "\n\n", persons[person], "\n")

               }) %>% paste(collapse = "\n")


# not run
cat(text)
# ### DP1 
# 
# Bray Laura had 0 temperature reporting for >/= 3 days 
# 
# ### DP2 
# 
# Despain Taylor and Housum Zachary and Herman Trenton had 0 temperature reporting for 2 consecutive readings 
# 
# ### DP3 
# 
# NA 
# 
# ### DP4 
# 
# Burgette Lesley had 1 temperature reporting/day for >/= 5 days
```

(inside a chunk)

Then just put `r text` in your markdown. It will render your wished output.

Comment: Actually, `DP1` has 2 compliance criteria, so 2 bullet points, so I have adapted your code in `persons`, FALSE argument to `paste(non_compliants$Text[which(non_compliants$Department == x)]`. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

using pander to output the bullet-list

Code is like this:

```
non_compliants <- df %>% 
  group_by(Department, `Non-compliance Criteria`) %>% 
  summarise(Text =paste("*", paste(paste(`Staff Name`, collapse = " and "), "had", unique(`Non-compliance Criteria`)))) %>% 
  ungroup()

non<-non_compliants %>% 
  group_by(Department) %>%
  summarise(messages= paste(Text, collapse = " \n "))

library(pander)
panderOptions("list.style", 'bullet')


non %>% pander(keep.line.breaks = TRUE,style = 'grid', justify = 'left')
```

[image]